# Injecting a gmock object

Tags: c++, qt, googletest, googlemock

For educational purposes I'm writing a Pacman alike game in Qt and C++. Main part of game works correctly, but now I need to test it with Googletest framework. I read about dependency injection and tryied to implement it into my project.

Project consists of few classes like ghost, pacman etc and a "Game" class that is QGraphicsView and also holds pointers to those object. The problem is, that when I construct "Game" class and pass a poiter to mock_pacman object it doesn't use it's mocked methods and doesn't seem to detect usage of mock_pacman (when I try EXPECT_CALL(..) the test fails). As the example I will just post part of code that refers to simplest method:

Constructors of "Game" class:

```
Game(QWidget * parent=nullptr) {...};
Game(QVector<ghost*> GhostArray, pacman * _player, PacmanBoard * Board, QWidget * parent=nullptr)
```

Secound constructor just puts _player as a member

Method I would like to test:

```
    int Game::getPacmanDirection()
{
    return player->getActualDirection();
}
```

Mock of Pacman:

```
    class mock_pacman: public pacman
{
public:
    virtual ~mock_pacman()=default;
    MOCK_METHOD1(keyPressEvent,void(QKeyEvent *));
    MOCK_METHOD0(getPosition,QPointF());
    MOCK_METHOD1(setPosition,void(QPointF()));
    MOCK_METHOD0(update,void());
    MOCK_METHOD0(getAnimationPhase,void());
    MOCK_METHOD1(setAnimationPhase,void(int));
    MOCK_METHOD0(animate,void());
    MOCK_METHOD0(getActualDirection,int());
    MOCK_METHOD0(getLastMove,QPoint());
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(pos,QPointF());

};
```

Google test:

```
    TEST(GameClassTests, GettingPacmanRealDirection)
{


  mock_pacman * m_pacman = new mock_pacman();
  mock_pacmanboard m_board;
  mock_ghost ghost0(0);
  mock_ghost ghost1(1);
  mock_ghost ghost2(2);
  mock_ghost ghost3(3);

  QVector<ghost*> m_ghost_vector{&ghost0,&ghost1,&ghost2,&ghost3};
  EXPECT_CALL(*m_pacman,getActualDirection());

  Game * game = new Game(m_ghost_vector,m_pacman,&m_board);
  game->getPacmanDirection();

  delete m_pacman;
};
```

Test resault:

```
[ RUN      ] GameClassTests.GettingPacmanRealDirection
../PacmanTests/tst_alltests.h:110: Failure
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*m_pacman, getActualDirection())...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[  FAILED  ] GameClassTests.GettingPacmanRealDirection (4 ms)
```

Function getActualDirection() in pacman original class is marked as virtual.
I tried to do it with other methods, to use test fixture, to pass a reference and many other variations.

Where I make mistake?

Comment: Are `pacman`'s methods delcared virtual?

Comment: yes, they are virtual

Comment: I can't find the error in the given code. Could you show me the implementation of the second constructor of `Game` and the declaration of `pacman`?

Comment: Thanks for your interest - meanwhile I have found solution. I've created pure abstract class, with all interface methods =0, both mock_pacman and pacman inherits from it and pointer in game class is type of this abstract class. Now it works as it should.